# Trials not starting from 1 - Negative binomial

Tags: r, probability, distributions, negative-binomial-distribution

Trying to tabulate the pmf and cdf of a negative binomial distribution. I have a probability of `0.75`, and an success of `2`, where the number of trials starts at 2 (`x = 2, 3, ...`).

I am using r (the language) to calculate and I'm aware that the definitions of the negative binomial are different from my x, but is it a case of starting the vector from 2 to make the distributions match or is there something more complicated? Is the code below going to ensure the distributions passed into the `dnbinom` and `pnbinom` functions match up with `x`?

```
df <- data.frame(X = 2:20, 
           pmf = dnbinom(x = 2:20, size, prob),
           cdf = pnbinom(q = 2:20, size, prob, lower.tail = TRUE))
```

The PMF that is outputted from this is:

```
x   2.000 3.000 4.000 5.000 6.000    7
pmf 0.105 0.035 0.011 0.003 0.001    0
```

Comment: There are several 'kinds' of negative binomial distribution. Please show the PMF for the one you are using.

Comment: @BruceET - Thanks for the reply. I'm fairly new to stats, the PMF I am using is the one outputted from the code above (added to the question). The only information I have is that X has a negative binomial distribution with r = 2 and p = 3/4. How would I find out the PMF?

Comment: Novice or not, you can look at your text for the explanation of the negative binomial distribution:  Are you counting Bernoulli trials _up to and including_ the occurrence of the $r$th Success, or are you counting Failures _before_ the $r$th Success? Or counting something else?

Comment: @BruceET My apologies, I misunderstood. Bernoulli trials up to and including second success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the indexing of the vectors passed into the `dnbinom` and `pnbinom` functions to start at `0` rather than `2`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 2:12, 
           pmf = dnbinom(x = 0:10, size, prob),
           cdf = pnbinom(q = 0:10, size, prob, lower.tail = TRUE))
```

This leads to the expected output:

```
x   2.000 3.000 4.000 5.000 6.000 7.000 8.000    9
pmf 0.562 0.281 0.105 0.035 0.011 0.003 0.001    0
cdf 0.563 0.844 0.949 0.984 0.995 0.999 1.000    1
```